# Gem 'coffee-rails' Load Error: HOME environment variable (or HOMEDRIVE and HOMEPATH) must be set and point to a directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I try to deploy Ruby on Rails with nginx and passenger.But I get following error in /var/log/nginx/error.log

```
[ E 2018-09-19 12:07:12.5312 24363/Tb age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:221 ]: Could not spawn process for application /home/example/test_app: The application encountered the following error: There was an error while trying to load the gem 'coffee-rails'.
Gem Load Error is: HOME environment variable (or HOMEDRIVE and HOMEPATH) must be set and point to a directory
Backtrace for gem load error is:
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rb-readline-0.5.5/lib/rbreadline.rb:1097:in `<module:RbReadline>'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rb-readline-0.5.5/lib/rbreadline.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rb-readline-0.5.5/lib/readline.rb:10:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rb-readline-0.5.5/lib/readline.rb:10:in `<module:Readline>'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rb-readline-0.5.5/lib/readline.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/line_editor/readline.rb:2:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/line_editor/readline.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/line_editor.rb:2:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/line_editor.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/base.rb:8:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/base.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/group.rb:1:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/group.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/generators.rb:4:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/generators.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/coffee-rails-4.2.2/lib/coffee/rails/engine.rb:2:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/coffee-rails-4.2.2/lib/coffee/rails/engine.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/coffee-rails-4.2.2/lib/coffee-rails.rb:2:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/coffee-rails-4.2.2/lib/coffee-rails.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.4/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
/home/example/test_app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/example/test_app/config/environment.rb:2:in `require_relative'
/home/example/test_app/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
config.ru:3:in `require_relative'
config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
config.ru:1:in `new'
config.ru:1:in `<main>'
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:101:in `eval'
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:101:in `preload_app'
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:189:in `block in <module:App>'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:380:in `run_block_and_record_step_progress'
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:188:in `<module:App>'
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'
Bundler Error Backtrace:
 (Bundler::GemRequireError)
  Error ID: e59091b1
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-gd9d3n.html

[ E 2018-09-19 12:07:12.5374 24363/T7 age/Cor/Con/CheckoutSession.cpp:276 ]: [Client 1-1] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is e59091b1. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
```

my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end


gem 'rails',        '5.1.4'
gem 'bcrypt',       '3.1.11'
gem 'faker',                   '1.7.3'
gem 'carrierwave',             '1.1.0'
gem 'mini_magick',             '4.7.0'
gem 'fog-aws',                 '2.0.0'
gem 'nokogiri',                '1.8.1'
gem 'will_paginate',           '3.1.6'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '1.0.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.7'
gem 'puma',         '3.9.1'
gem 'sass-rails',   '5.0.6'
gem 'uglifier',     '3.2.0'
gem 'coffee-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.3.1'
gem 'turbolinks',   '5.0.1'
gem 'jbuilder',     '2.7.0'
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

gem 'activeadmin'
gem 'devise'
gem 'trix'
gem 'shrine'
gem 'mina'
gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.13'
gem 'rb-readline'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug',  '9.0.6', platform: :mri
  gem 'pry'

end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console',           '3.5.1'
  gem 'listen',                '3.0.8'
  gem 'spring',                '2.0.2'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '2.0.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rails-controller-testing', '1.0.2'
  gem 'minitest', '5.10.3'
  gem 'minitest-reporters',       '1.1.14'
  gem 'guard',                    '2.13.0'
  gem 'guard-minitest',           '2.4.4'
end

group :production do
  # gem 'pg', '0.20.0'
  gem 'fog', '1.42'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

All information I got about "HOME enviromment" is on Windows but I am on Ubuntu 16.04. So I have no idea of the error.
Well, it's my first time to ask questions in stackoverflow. Maybe it's not clear enough.

Comment: Can you update your question with `Gemfile` ? Have you installed `nodejs` ?

Comment: Thanks for your kind suggestion. I had updated the question with my Gemfile. I had already installed node.js because there was another error like this:"Gem Load Error is: Could not find a JavaScript runtime." before and I solve it by adding "gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby" to my Gemfile.

Comment: The issue seems to be with `rb-readline`. Can you get rid of it and try ?

Comment: It works! Thank you so much. Although it seems that another error occured as `Errno::EACCES (Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /home/example/test_app/public/uploads/tmp/1537338928-28162-0001-7509):`. Well I think its not a problem. Best wishes for you.