# Passenger can't load coffee-rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am trying to convert my application from using Ruby on Rails's web brick web server and, instead, use Apache + Passenger. I seem to be having the hardest time trying to accomplish this. Currently, I am getting the following error when navigating to my site while it's running Apache + Passenger:

```
App 31495 output:  [passenger_native_support.so] trying to compile for the current user (nobody) and Ruby interpreter...
App 31495 output:      (set PASSENGER_COMPILE_NATIVE_SUPPORT_BINARY=0 to disable)
App 31495 output:      Warning: compilation didn't succeed. To learn why, read this file:
App 31495 output:      /tmp/passenger_native_support-1p5ww5z.log
App 31495 output:  [passenger_native_support.so] finding downloads for the current Ruby interpreter...
App 31495 output:      (set PASSENGER_DOWNLOAD_NATIVE_SUPPORT_BINARY=0 to disable)
App 31495 output:      Could not download https://github.com/phusion/passenger/releases/download/release-6.0.2/rubyext-ruby-2.5.1-x86_64-linux.tar.gz: 2019-09-26 10:17:17 ERROR 404: Not Found.
App 31495 output:      Trying next mirror...
App 31495 output:      Could not download https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/binaries/passenger/by_release/6.0.2/rubyext-ruby-2.5.1-x86_64-linux.tar.gz: 2019-09-26 10:17:17 ERROR 404: Not Found.
App 31495 output:      Trying next mirror...
App 31495 output:      Could not download https://s3.amazonaws.com/phusion-passenger/binaries/passenger/by_release/6.0.2/rubyext-ruby-2.5.1-x86_64-linux.tar.gz: 2019-09-26 10:17:17 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
App 31495 output:  [passenger_native_support.so] will not be used (can't compile or download)
App 31495 output:   --> Passenger will still operate normally.
App 31495 output: Error: The application encountered the following error: There was an error while trying to load the gem 'coffee-rails'.
App 31495 output: Gem Load Error is: HOME environment variable (or HOMEDRIVE and HOMEPATH) must be set and point to a directory
<snipped>
```

The first thing I needed to do was add:

```
PassengerRuby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/wrappers/ruby
```

to my apache configuration, and now I'm getting this error that appears to be related to the `coffee-rails` gem but I have no idea what I need to do about it.

What do I need to do to get this working?

According to this post, [Gem 'coffee-rails' Load Error: HOME environment variable (or HOMEDRIVE and HOMEPATH) must be set and point to a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52398592/gem-coffee-rails-load-error-home-environment-variable-or-homedrive-and-homep), the issue was with his `rb-readline` and the suggestion was to remove that. I tried removing that from my gemfile and the following error occurred:

```
[ E 2019-09-26 10:25:32.5273 31834/Th age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:221 ]: Could not spawn process for application /var/www/test: The application encountered the following error: You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
updated Gemfile.lock to version control.

If this is a development machine, remove the /var/www/test/Gemfile freeze
by running `bundle install --no-deployment`.

You have deleted from the Gemfile:
* rb-readline
 (Bundler::ProductionError)
  Error ID: 7b2f2a89
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-Nd6b5y.html

[ E 2019-09-26 10:25:32.5302 31834/T9 age/Cor/Con/CheckoutSession.cpp:276 ]: [Client 1-2] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is 7b2f2a89. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
```

Ok so then I try to run `bundle install`, and then I get this error:

```
Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root users on this machine.
Your Gemfile lists the gem wicked_pdf (>= 0) more than once.
You should probably keep only one of them.
Remove any duplicate entries and specify the gem only once (per group).
While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of one of them later.
You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
updated Gemfile.lock to version control.

If this is a development machine, remove the /var/www/test/Gemfile freeze
by running `bundle install --no-deployment`.

You have deleted from the Gemfile:
* rb-readline
```

which leaves me stuck again and I can't figure out how to get through this or if trying to resolve this error is even necessary due to the other issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best answer, but I was able to remove the gem from the Gemfile from another instance of the application, run `bundle install` there, and then copy the app back over to the `/var/www/` directory. I have absolutely no idea why this was required, but it worked.

The next set of issues I had related to permission issues, so I just gave `www-data` ownership of the entire rails directory.